# What is the main difference between PATCH and PUT request?

Tags: http, patch, put, http-verbs

I am using a `PUT` request in my Rails application. Now, a new HTTP verb, `PATCH` has been implemented by browsers. So, I want to know what the main difference between `PATCH` and `PUT` requests are, and when we should use one or the other.

Answer (score 171):

HTTP verbs are probably one of the most cryptic things about the HTTP protocol. They exist, and there are many of them, but why do they exist?

Rails seems to want to support many verbs and add some verbs that aren't supported by web browsers natively.

Here's an exhaustive list of http verbs: http://annevankesteren.nl/2007/10/http-methods

There the HTTP patch from the official RFC: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/rfc5789/?include_text=1

> The *PATCH* method requests that a set of changes described in the
>   request entity be applied to the resource identified by the Request-
>   URI.  The set of changes is represented in a format called a "patch
>   document" identified by a media type. If the Request-URI does not
>   point to an existing resource, the server *MAY* create a new resource,
>   depending on the patch document type (whether it can logically modify
>   a null resource) and permissions, etc.
>
> The difference between the *PUT* and *PATCH* requests is reflected in the 
>   way the server processes the enclosed entity to modify the resource
>   identified by the Request-URI. In a *PUT* request, the enclosed entity 
>   is considered to be a modified version of the resource stored on the
>   origin server, and the client is requesting that the stored version be
>   replaced. **With *PATCH*, however, the enclosed entity contains a set  of
>   instructions describing how a resource currently residing on the
>   origin server should be modified to produce a new version.** The *PATCH* 
>   method affects the resource identified by the *Request-URI*, and it also
>   *MAY* have side effects on other resources; i.e., new resources may be
>   created, or existing ones modified, by the application of a *PATCH*.

As far as I know, the *PATCH* verb is not used as it is in rails applications... As I understand this, the RFC patch verb should be used to send patch instructions like when you do a diff between two files. Instead of sending the whole entity again, you send a patch that could be much smaller than resending the whole entity.

Imagine you want to edit a huge file. You edit 3 lines. Instead of sending the file back, you just have to send the diff. On the plus side, sending a patch request could be used to merge files asynchronously. A version control system could potentially use the *PATCH* verb to update code remotely.

One other possible use case is somewhat related to NoSQL databases, it is possible to store documents. Let say we use a JSON structure to send back and forth data from the server to the client. If we wanted to delete a field, we could use a syntax similar to the one in mongodb for [$unset](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/). Actually, the method used in mongodb to update documents could be probably used to handle json patches.

Taking this example:

```
db.products.update(
   { sku: "unknown" },
   { $unset: { quantity: "", instock: "" } }
)
```

We could have something like this:

```
PATCH /products?sku=unknown
{ "$unset": { "quantity": "", "instock": "" } }
```

Last, but not least, people can say whatever they want about HTTP verbs. There is only one truth, and the truth is in the RFCs.

Comment: It is important to note that RFC 5789 is still in proposal phase and has not been officially accepted and is currently flagged as 'irrata exist'. This 'best practice' is highly debated and technically PATCH is not yet part of the HTTP standard.

The only truth here is that since the RFC is unaccepted, you should not be doing it.

Comment: Even if it's still in proposal, it doesn't mean it shouldn't be used. If it was the case, we wouldn't be able to use websockets and many other rfcs that are still in proposal... Implementing the proposal is 100 times better than implementing something completely custom that nobody else implement.

Comment: BS. It's not "in proposal", and it's part of the HTTP standard (the standard, RFC 7231 delegates to an IANA registry for methods, and PATCH is listed there).

Comment: @JulianReschke if you read the second line of this RFC, you'll see that it's still marked as _PROPOSED STANDARD_. So no, the patch method is still in proposal. The rfc is here btw. https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5789 and the rfc7231 is also _PROPOSED STANDARD_. If you look at the RFC821 for example, it's marked as _INTERNET STANDARD_

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix I recommend to get involved with the IETF standards process then; you're seriously misunderstanding what "proposed standard" means in the IETF context. The fact that the core HTTP/1.1 spec itself is labeled "proposed" should be a hint...

Comment: @JulianReschke https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Standard#Proposed_Standard ... It's not my word. A proposed standard doesn't mean you can't implement it fine as I explained above. It doesn't mean that it's not stable enough to implement... but it is still in proposal unless it's marked as Internet Standard... I'm not sure how you're arguing on that. It's called "proposed standard" it can't mean anything else than a proposal. If you want to argue that a proposed standard can be used. It's exactly what I wrote.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix my point being that it is non-sensical to argue that something isn't part of HTTP because it's a "proposed standard" when HTTP *itself* is just a proposed standard. So "PATCH" is *exactly* as standard as "GET". Over and out.

Comment: Well not exactly, you can't say GET and PATCH are as standard as each other because both rfcs are in proposal... PATCH might not even be supported by some browsers. Apparently Windows Edge doesn't from this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24257327/http-patch-support-in-browsers. Find a browser that doesn't support GET.

Comment: How about trying? There doesn't seem to be a problem with PATCH in Edge, as far as I can tell. Try <https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/xhrmethods.html>

Answer (score 143):

I spent couple of hours with google and found the answer [here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/whats-the-differences-between-put-and-patch?page=1)

**PUT** =>
   **If user can update all or just a portion of the record**, use PUT (user controls what gets updated)

```
PUT /users/123/email
new.email@example.org
```

**PATCH** => 
   **If user can only update a partial record**, say just an email address (application controls what can be updated), use PATCH.

```
PATCH /users/123
[description of changes]
```

Why `Patch`

`PUT` method need more bandwidth or handle full resources instead on partial. So `PATCH` was introduced to reduce the bandwidth.

Explanation about **PATCH**

`PATCH` is a method that is not safe, nor idempotent, and allows full and partial updates and side-effects on other resources.

`PATCH` is a method which enclosed entity contains a set of instructions describing how a resource currently residing on the origin server should be modified to produce a new version.

```
PATCH /users/123
[
  { "op": "replace", "path": "/email", "value": "new.email@example.org" }
]
```

[Here](http://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/) more information about put and patch

Comment: Why is this PATCH not safe?

Comment: `PATCH` among `POST`, `PUT` etc. is not "safe", because it modifies your data (has side effects). Compared to `GET`, `OPTIONS` etc. (safe methods) where you can call the endpoints multiple times without any side effects.

Comment: PATCH was NOT introduced to solely save bandwith. As RFC 5789 states:


> "A new method is necessary to improve interoperability and prevent
   errors."

In multi parallel environment having only PUTs that include the rest of the payload would increase the risk of modification of other attributes of the resource. PATCH solves such problem.

Answer (score 132):

**put:**
If I want to update my `first` name, then I send a **put** request:

```
{ "first": "Nazmul", "last": "hasan" }
```

But here is a problem with using `put` request: When I want to send `put` request I have to send all two parameters that is `first` and `last` (whereas I only need to update `first`) so it is mandatory to send them all again with `put` request.

**patch:**
`patch` request, on the other hand, says: only specify the `data` which you need to `update` and it won't be affecting or changing other data.
So no need to send  all values again. Do I only need to change `first` name? Well, It only suffices to specify `first` in `patch` request.

Comment: IMO, this is the most straightforward answer.

Comment: Quick and easy to understand!

Comment: My favorite also, directly to the point! Perfect

Comment: Yes, crisp and accurate.

Comment: Long story, short answer 

Answer (score 31):

**Here are the difference between POST, PUT and PATCH methods of a HTTP protocol.**

**POST**

A HTTP.POST method always creates a new resource on the server. Its a non-idempotent request i.e. if user hits same requests 2 times it would create another new resource if there is no constraint.

http post method is like a INSERT query in SQL which always creates a new record in database.

Example: Use POST method to save new user, order etc where backend server decides the resource id for new resource.

**PUT**

In HTTP.PUT method the resource is first identified from the URL and if it exists then it is updated otherwise a new resource is created. When the target resource exists it overwrites that resource with a complete new body. That is HTTP.PUT method is used to CREATE or UPDATE a resource.

http put method is like a MERGE query in SQL which inserts or updates a record depending upon whether the given record exists.

PUT request is idempotent i.e. hitting the same requests twice would update the existing recording (No new record created). In PUT method the resource id is decided by the client and provided in the request url.

Example: Use PUT method to update existing user or order.

**PATCH**

A HTTP.PATCH method is used for partial modifications to a resource i.e. delta updates.

http patch method is like a UPDATE query in SQL which sets or updates selected columns only and not the whole row.

Example: You could use PATCH method to update order status.

PATCH /api/users/40450236/order/10234557

Request Body: {status: 'Delivered'}

Comment: Good job! Self-Explanatory

Answer (score 20):

### Explanation by Analogy

A lecturer of mine purchased an Alpha Romeo. It had a defective engine (quelle surprise).

There are two ways the problem could be fixed:

- Replace the entire car (**put** request),  or
- Just replace the defective engine (**patch** request) - i.e. "patch" up the car, rather than replace it entirely.

---

No apologies for naming the brand.

He would ramble on about how the dealer laughed in his face, when he complained.

If you make defective cars, and refuse to replace them (via your dealer), you deserve the reputation you're gonna get. "[Italian Trash](https://youtu.be/kbcY2kH5tac)". And a well deserved reputation. Want reliability? Buy  Japanese.

Example:

```
GET toyota_inspection # inspect the car at the dealership, see the new Toyota
POST toyota_path # manufacture the car

PUT toyota_path ## (you should know the answer to this one!?)
PATCH toyota_path, params: {engine: 4_cyclinder, seats: nappa_leather} ## What is this doing?
```

Examples / stories used to help reinforce the concept, otherwise you might forget 10 seconds later.

Answer (score 9):

There are limitations in PUT over PATCH while making updates. Using PUT requires us to specify all attributes even if we want to change only one attribute.
But if we use the PATCH method we can update only the fields we need and there is no need to mention all the fields. PATCH does not allow us to modify a value in an array, or remove an attribute or array entry.

Answer (score 5):

According to HTTP terms, The `PUT` request is just-like a database update statement.
`PUT` - is used for modifying existing resource (Previously POSTED). On the other hand the `PATCH` request is used to update some portion of existing resource.

For Example:

**Customer Details:**

```
// This is just a example.

firstName = "James";
lastName = "Anderson";
email = "email@domain.com";
phoneNumber = "+92 1234567890";
//..
```

When we want to update to entire record ? we have to use `Http` `PUT` `verb` for that.

**such as:**

```
// Customer Details Updated.

firstName = "James++++";
lastName = "Anderson++++";
email = "email@Updated.com";
phoneNumber = "+92 0987654321";
//..
```

On the other hand if we want to update only the portion of the record not the entire record then go for `Http` `PATCH` `verb`.
**such as:**

```
   // Only Customer firstName and lastName is Updated.

    firstName = "Updated FirstName";
    lastName = "Updated LastName";
   //..
```

**PUT VS POST:**

When using `PUT` request we have to send all parameter such as firstName, lastName, email, phoneNumber Where as In `patch` request only send the parameters which one we want to update and it won't effecting or changing other data.

For more details please visit : https://fullstack-developer.academy/restful-api-design-post-vs-put-vs-patch/

Answer (score 2):

**PUT** and **PATCH** methods are similar in nature, but there is a key difference.

**PUT** - in **PUT** request, the enclosed entity would be considered as the modified version of a resource which residing on server and it would be replaced by this modified entity.

**PATCH** - in **PATCH** request, enclosed entity contains the set of instructions that how the entity which residing on server, would be modified to produce a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

Put and Patch method are similar . But in rails it has different metod
If we want to update/replace whole record then we have to use Put method.
If we want to update particular record use Patch method.

Answer (score 0):

Differences between PUT and PATCH
The main difference between PUT and PATCH requests is witnessed in the way the server processes the enclosed entity to update the resource identified by the Request-URI. When making a PUT request, the enclosed entity is viewed as the modified version of the resource saved on the original server, and the client is requesting to replace it. However, with PATCH, the enclosed entity boasts a set of instructions that describe how a resource stored on the original server should be partially modified to create a new version.

The second difference is when it comes to idempotency. HTTP PUT is said to be idempotent since it always yields the same results every after making several requests. On the other hand, HTTP PATCH is basically said to be non-idempotent. However, it can be made to be idempotent based on where it is implemented.