# Using HTTP PATCH - real example

Tags: javascript, http

I am trying to figure out how can I implement a HTTP patch in my application. I have never used it before. I use Express.js and sequelize (MySQL).

I looked on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21660791/what-is-the-main-difference-between-patch-and-put-request) and on internet for real life example, but could not find anything of real value. Those links gave me better understanding what is PATCH, but I still fail to see its benefit in my case. It must be something I am missing.

This is my simplified setup:

```
router:
basePath: 
    controller: PutUser
    method: PUT
    path: /user/:userId/

Payload:
{email: 'newemail@hello.com'}

Controller:
Then here I find the user by its id and give the payload. User gets updated
```

What is confusing me, is if I were to implement a PATCH, the only things that changes is in router, I use PATCH instead. I also use userId to find the user and change its email. What am I missing? Is this how it is supposed to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not missing anything. The difference between PUT and PATCH is more semantically. The method itself does not deliver much additional information/requirement in HTTP level. According to [RFC5789](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2.1), using PUT or PATCH depends on your server-side logic:

> The difference between the PUT and PATCH requests is reflected in the
> way the server processes the enclosed entity to modify the resource
> identified by the Request-URI.

Thus, if your `user` resource has many fields, such as email, name, address, age etc, then `PATCH` is the better choice if you only want to change email. If your `user` resource only have email field, or if you want to reset all fields information, then `PUT` is the better choice.

I guess you are confused because this "update email" operation is an "override" operation, which makes it very similar to PUT or POST. There is a more appropriate example though (pseudocode):

```
PATCH /user/<userId>
Payload:
{
    patchField: 'age', 
    patchOperation: 'X+1'
}
```