# what is the difference between put and patch in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In rails the routes can be created using

```
resources :vehicals
```

so, that will create many routes which will produce the basic routes required for the CRUD operation, But I am confused between the 2 routes i.e.

```
PATCH  /vehicals/:id(.:format)        vehicals#update
PUT    /vehicals/:id(.:format)        vehicals#update
```

please clear which is to use  while update.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the main difference between PATCH and PUT request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21660791/what-is-the-main-difference-between-patch-and-put-request)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it creates routes for PATCH and PUT for me, on Rails 5.0

Comment: @SteveTurczyn: yes, I just tested myself. Looks like compatibility layer. Costs them nothing to create the route, so why not?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev exactly. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In rails there's no effective difference, and you can see from your routes that they call the same controller action.

Because rails only updates fields that are included in the view form and leaves other fields unchanged, it effectively has always implemented "PATCH" logic even before 'PATCH' was ever officially introduced.

Current Rails forms default to method `post` for sending new records and `patch` for updating existing records.