# what is the right way to handle multiple HTTP methods with single URI and single request

Tags: rest, api, http-method

I want to understand what should be the right request/response structure and API design to solve below problem.
I have 2 entities let say Abc and Xyz. And Xyz has a foreign key of Abc.
So, to create a record for Xyz, there has to be mapped Abc record.

Now for request structure point of view, I need to create one POST request for Abc that is like

```
POST /Abc
```

This is pretty much straightforward. But the problem is with Xyz.
The requirement is whenever a user came for to create Xyz, he may also request to update the attached Abc record, too.
For example,
I have created a record for Abc with id 5. Now, whenever I want to create a corresponding Xyz record, I will request to update the Abc record with id 5 and create a new Xyz record for this foreign key.
So, 
    PATCH /Abc 
and 
    POST /Xyz
But the client requests only once and share whole data on single URI.

So, what is the right way to handle multiple HTTP methods on single URI?
Should I create POST request or PATCH?

I couldn't create 2 requests because the client wants this process as transactional.

Comment: You should tell us what language you are using.

Comment: This is mare related to API design problem rather than a language. But for reference, I am using Spring-Java.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I guess you should think this

> I couldn't create 2 requests because the client wants this process as transactional.

in an other way. As I see it the requirement for transactional might just mean - I might be terribly wrong on this so find out the truth - that when there is also an update to `Abc` the process of creating a new `Xyz` is transactional with updating `Abc`. So the `Xyz` is not created if the update for `Abc` fails (or vice versa) and some error is returned.

So you might be able to create two endpoints:

- one with just **POST**:ing a new `Xyz`
- another for creating a new `Xyz` and update `Abc` at the same time transactionally

So you might be able to create two endpoints. More interesting here is that is the latter **POST** or **PATCH**? It seems to somehow be both, yes.

However see - for example - [this question & accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21660791/6413377), there is about **PATCH**:

> The PATCH method requests that a set of changes described in the request entity be applied to the resource identified by the Request-URI

Now, the following question is that is the changed `Abc` *identified by the Request-URI*? If not then it is - as I understand this - a **POST**.

Which means you should need only one **POST** endpoint that checks if there is a need and does transactional updates id needed. But maybe it would still be better to have separate endpoints.

Comment: So, for 2 endpoints the situation is pretty much clear and hence the solution, too. But here the issue is I want just a single end-point. So, there may an issue with its response code too. That PATCH /Abc is successful but POST /Xyz is not. How to handle those? And related to your question of change of Abc is identified by URI or not? That's up to us as the front-end (client) just deals with the end result. My preference is YES but I will happy to adopt a robust solution. Just one constraint is, there is just 1 API call and I have to perform 2 trans.

Comment: Well I stated _Which means you should need only one POST endpoint_ so I think you should not create two. So about the _identified by the URI_ I left it to you to decide but if you "POST" a new `Xyz` is it not so that the changed `Abc` is a part of the new `Xyz` and you might not necessarily identify `Abc` in the URI? So **not** something like `POST(or PATCH) /Xyz/{alteredAbcId}/Abc` but just `POST /Xyz` where `Xyz` contains altered `Abc`?